# Combine 'if' statements into one comparison operator chain

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me in making one comparison operator chain out of the code below. I am thinking in terms of

```
if 0 <= file >= 7 or 0 <= rank >= 7:
    file = 0
    rank = 0
```

Here's the code to concise:

```
if file <= 0:
    file = 0

if rank <= 0:
    rank = 0

if file => 7:
    file = 7

if rank => 7:
    rank = 7
```

Comment: Is my suggestion any good? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: in the top code you say make rank and file = 0 if not within 0 to 7.  In the second code you say limit those values to 0 to 7.  So, what is it you really want?

Comment: I want this: if file is smaller than 0, then apply 0 as a value to file, and also if file is bigger than 7, then apply 7 as a value to file. Do this exactly the same for the rank. Do this all in a one simple comparison operator chain.

Comment: Chaining doesn't really help you here, because each comparison results in a different action if true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, but what I ended up with is this:

```
file = 0 if file < 0 else 7 if file > 7 else file
rank = 0 if rank < 0 else 7 if rank > 7 else rank
```

Comment: The status of `file` shouldn't affect the value of `rank`, or vice versa.

Comment: I mean, it's not the *only* solution. You've already been presented with alternatives. You haven't explained why you don't want to use `min` and `max`...

Comment: I hate the syntax `func(another_func(...))`. Looks ugly.

Comment: @BoštjanMejak so separate it onto two lines... have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
file = max(min(file, 7), 0)
rank = max(min(rank, 7), 0)
```

`min(file, 7)` will return `7` at most; `max(x, 0)` will return `0` or something bigger.

---

you can only use chaining to check if something is within a range:

```
0 <= x <= 7
```

you cannot use chaining to check if something is outside a range:

```
0 <= x >= 7
```

will always be `False` (as it evaluates as `(0 <= x) and (x >= 7)`).

---

if your variables are integers you could use:

```
x not in range(0, 8)
```

Comment: This is not comparison operator chaining.

Comment: Well, I need help in comparison operator chaining. Can you verify if the suggestion of my edited question is any good?

Comment: You either need what you asked in your question, or you 'need' operator chaining.  Perhaps you are unsure what the term means?  At any rate, the answer from Hiro seems to solve the problem you pose

Comment: Upvoted for the range() suggestion. Maybe like this:
`if file not in range(0, 8):
    file = 0
if rank not in range(0, 8):
    rank = 0`

Comment: @BoštjanMejak that doesn't do what you asked for though, you asked to upper bound the variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
def clip(number: int, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int) -> int:
    clipped_lower = max(lower_bound, number)
    clipped = min(clipped_lower, upper_bound)
    return clipped

lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = 7
file = clip(file, lower_bound, upper_bound)
rank = clip(rank, lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

If you already happen to be using `numpy`, then it already has `clip`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html

Comment: This is not comparison operator chaining.

Comment: *"I want this: if file is smaller than 0, then apply 0 as a value to file, and also if file is bigger than 7, then apply 7 as a value to file. "* --> this solution answers this exactly. You do not want comparison operator chaining, you want a clean and readable solution to clipping values.

Comment: I don't like clipping. I wanna know if it's even possible to do comparison operator chaining for my task at hand.

Comment: It is not possible. Why don't you like clipping? That is what your task is doing...

Comment: A chained comparison like `0 <= rank <= 7` will only tell you if `rank` is in the interval or not; it doesn't tell you anything about which "side" of the interval `rank` appears on if the expression is false, which means you don't know whether to do `rank = 0` or `rank = 7`.